# Blackberry spark SDK Identity configuration

Tags: javascript, php, bb-messenger

I am using BlackBerry Spark Communications SDK to integrate chat system in my web app. It requires OAuth 2.0 for Identity Management. I am using bshaffer/oauth2-server-php library for generating OAuth 2.0 tokens. When initiating the SDK I am getting "Invalid Token Audience" error when BBM endpoint 
https://profile.sandbox.bbmenterprise.com/domains/8874cfde-5524-4df1-9609-360e1a8ba0f2/token?userId=-VvarBIAtPdQo61zAL4Ygzng-KKPmap3VDVoaQ6eQxA&requireMinToken=true

is called.

SDK Reference: https://developer.blackberry.com/files/bbm-enterprise/documents/guide/html/identityManagement.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add some more detail to your questions
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your requested question is not clear. Please ellobrate your question clearly and cripsy.

Answer (score 1):

have you configured your OAuth2 endpoint on account.blackberry.com ? You must provide your token info endpoint URL as well as a user info endpoint URL, and finally your OAuth clientID.

To do this, navigate to account.blackberry.com (create an account if you haven't already), select 'Application' from the left hand menu and then click "Add Application". Next give your app a name and check the box for 'Communications Services' and create your app. Finally under the 'Communication Service' tab on the next screen, under the sandbox tab, provide your endpoint info and clientID.

Comment: Yes I have already added token info endpoint URL, user info endpoint URL and OAuth clientID.

Comment: I am getting the error "Failed to fetch BBM token.  Rejecting 2 promise(s) with error=BBMEnterprise.Error.PermanentFailure: PermanentFailure."